# How to drop into R shell after executing commands from file in R

Tags: r, plot

In Python, running the interpreter with the `-i` flag first executes the script, then drops back into the interpreter

```
python -i hello.py
Hello world
>>> print("Python ftw")
Python ftw
>>>
```

which allows me to type commands and reach the variables after execution.

With R, this seems to be of great difficulty. I have been searching online for some time, and am surprised to see there is not so many results with the keywords "R run file shell interpreter".

With R, you can use

1. `$ R -f myfile.R` which executes and then exits the interpreter
2. `$ Rscript myfile.R` which still does the same thing.

Even worse, it does not plot when run like this and just exits without showing any signs that something has been plotted.

So, to repeat my question:

1. How do I make R to drop into the R shell after running commands from a file, a.k.a. a script?
2. Concurrently, how can I make R really plot the plots and not close them off immediately?

I can do these with Python, MATLAB, Octave, Ruby and many others, and should be able to do with R too.

Comment: Why so arrogantly philosophical with your comments on what answers you wont accept? You are taking a favor, and not doing a favor to others by asking this question. More than 40% of your question is filled with that irrelevant stuff

Comment: Its a rant. You should use python, or MATLAB, OCTAVE, or possibly ruby. Python meets your needs and you don't need to rail on anything.

Comment: Because I anticipate that more than 90% of the answers will be so, and I don't want to clarify later. Sorry if it seems arrogant.

Comment: I do not know if this will meet your standards, and not sure if this works or not, so not writing an answer but heres what you can do maybe. Create a shell script and pass your file name as command line argument to the script, which will be then run under 1 command in shell script. Second line of shell script can be the command which takes you in R interpreter

Comment: @MohitC seems possible. But can I recall the plots?

Comment: You should be able to since it happens under same terminal session right

Comment: I deleted the rant part per negative reactions, but I doubt that I will still get an answer. That is probably because the elegant solution requires that R interpreter be rewritten, and that would not happen so easily.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your two questions separately:

1. How do I drop into a shell after my script has executed?

The function "[browser](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/browser)" called with no arguments will allow to to drop into a shell on the line that it's called. Appending this to your script should do the trick.

2. How do I save graphics when not run in interactive mode?

First, check that there isn't a pdf file being created in your working directory. Depending on how you're running R, I believe it may be named "Rplots.pdf". Personally, however, I prefer to explicitly save graphics to a particular file, as such:

```
pdf("temp.pdf")
plot(rnorm(100))
dev.off()
```

which will save the plot in a new file called temp.pdf (and will overwrite any existing file by that name, so watch out).

Functions analagous to "pdf" exist for other image formats if you would prefer that.